# Laravel Queues delay length

Tags: php, laravel, jobs

Is there a maximum Length of time i can delay a Laravel Job?
I need to delay a job for up to 14 days, and i can't find any documentation about delay length.

```
$job = (new SendReminderEmail($user))->delay(89000);
```

is this ok?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Carbon and Queue::later

```
$date = Carbon::now()->addMinutes(20160);

Queue::later($date, 'SendReminderEmail@send', array('user' => $user));
```

Comment: This does not answer to the OP question...